# Excel 2010 Format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I make a presentaion with excel twice a week and need to know how can I resize all of my rows with out going smaller than 60.00(80 pix)? Some rows have more information than others so i have to scroll through 1500 rows and find the ones that need to be resized.  I cant lock the cells because the information is constantly moving every time i updated my work sheet.

Comment: Welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @CharlieRB the title includes the Excel version.

Comment: Duh. Yep, it sure does. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you know how to add code to `ThisWorkbook` in VBA explorer (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and how to run macros.

Not sure what version you're using, but this code was tested on 2010. This VBA will create a macro you can run to format the rows to word wrap, then check the row height. If it's not at least 60 it will set it to 60.

```
Sub SetRowHeight()
    For Each c In Range("A1:D1500") 'set this range to match your sheet
        c.EntireRow.WrapText = True
        If c.RowHeight < 60 Then c.RowHeight = 60
    Next c
End Sub
```

*Note: This does not change the column width.*

Comment: Just curious, but wouldn't that needlessly iterate over the range four times (once per column)? Intuitively, `Range("A1:A1500")` would seem to be a better choice.

Comment: I think both of these suggestions will make the rows 60,right? I want 60 in all rows except for rows that need to be larger than 60. Im wanting to see if a macro will do that to keep me from looking at all 1500 rows to find the 50 that need to be larger than 60.

Comment: I think both of these suggestions will make the rows 60,right? I want 60 in all rows except for rows that need to be larger than 60. Im wanting to see if a macro will do that to keep me from looking at all 1500 rows to find the 50 that need to be larger than 60.

Comment: @Anthony This will check the row is at least 60. If its already bigger, it will leave it alone.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling What if there are cells needing wrapped which aren't in `A1:A1500`? That would work if the data is only in the first column. In order to be able to add wrapping for the cells with a lot of text it needs to include the wider range. Obviously the user needs to set the range.

Answer (score 1):

You can click in the upper left cell to select all rows and columns in the workbook

[image: Select All]

The in the `Cells` section of the Ribbon select the `Format` dropdown:

[image: Format]

You can either AutoFit all Rows or use the `Row Height` dialog to set an explicit height.